# Apache solr with Typehead / Bloodhound

Tags: ajax, solr, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I'm using Apache solr with Typhead.js for searching in my application.  My problem is that I keep getting a CORS error when calling my solr API from an AJAX request on the client.  I am setting dataType: 'jsonp', but it's still giving me the CORS error.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  Am I setting the dataType in the wrong spot?

I am using typeahead version 0.11.1

Error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="typeahead.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <input class="typeahead">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var things = new Bloodhound({

        datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
        },

        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

        remote: {
            wildcard: '%QUERY',

            url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/MYCORE/select?q=name:%QUERY',

            ajax: {
                dataType: 'jsonp',

                data: {
                    'wt': 'json',

                },

                jsonp: 'json.wrf'
            },

            transform: function(response) {
                return $.map(response, function(value, key) {
                    return {
                        value: value.name
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // Instantiate Typeahead
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        hint: true,
        display: 'value',
        source: things
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I manually make an AJAX request it works fine.  I just cant seem to get it working with Bloodhound.

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL_TO_SOLR,
    success: function(data) {

        var docs = JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(docs);

        response($.map(jsonData, function(value, key) {
            return {
                label: value.name
            }
        }));
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'json.wrf'
});
```

This get's through to my solr server just fine.

Comment: This is generic Javascript question, not Solr or typeahead specific. The only Solr part here is that you should not be exposing Solr directly to the internet, so this header issue needs to be resolved on whatever you are actually exposing to the internet instead. Google the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* for explanation on what the header and how to add it.

Comment: I understand why I am getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error and what it means.  This is why I am setting the dataType to jsonp for the Bloodhound AJAX call.  I have read that this is the easiest route.  I have it working when I manually send an AJAX request but I can't seem to get it working with Bloodhounds remote: {} config.  This is why I assumed the question was Typeahead specific?

Comment: You might be right. In which case, I would open the developer console and see the URL contrusted by Bloodhound. If it is not the same as you get with jQuery, that might be the issue. I do not see ajax hash in the Bloodhound configuration. Does it definitely support those options?